# Couldn't download Eclipse Kepler - getting "Execution over HTTP is unsupported" error in browser

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-kepler

I could not download Eclipse Kepler on Ubuntu 12.04.

Link: http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/eclipse/downloads/drops4/R-4.3.2-201402211700/eclipse-SDK-4.3.2-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz
I am getting an error in the browser that just says "Execution over HTTP is unsupported."

How can I download the Eclipse Kepler version now?

Comment: Wow, that's kinda neat - I get the same thing for the link, and I'm running Windows - it basically makes the browser load a page that simply says "Execution over HTTP is unsupported"... Have you tried a different mirror? This sounds like something you would get better results from by asking on the Eclipse forums or bugzilla.

Comment: Looks like all the download links on http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-standard-432/keplersr2 are busted the same way...

Comment: I entered a bugzilla: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=445219

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you were using the links on https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-standard-432/keplersr2 to do the download - for some reason they are broken. I've submitted a [bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=445219) to Eclipse about this.

If you download Eclipse Kepler from https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/Kepler/SR2 as a starting point instead, you can then choose to download from different mirrors, which do indeed work.